# How to launch the sqlite manager (firefox add-on) directly without launching the firefox first?

Tags: sqlite, firefox, sqlitemanager

I recently switched over to Chrome from my old favorite Firefox for browsing, but use the SQLite manager very often. Just trying to see if I can avoid opening and closing of the empty firefox windoow everytime I use the sqlite manager. Don't think Chrome has this extension. Does it?

Comment: I've similar problem. I'd installed the `addon` it worked well. But maybe after updating the firefox it blown up. I'm unable to start `sqlite-manager` anymore. Please anybody know where did it get installed or how could I use it? I'd read this [artical](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/wiki/FAQ#I_have_installed_SQLite_Manager,_but_I_cannot_find_how_to_start) but doesn't seems worthy.

Comment: I don't see why this question is off topic. SQLite Manager is a very useful tool for developers using SQLite, and it's non-trivial to open is directly.